# Picasso image load issue in android

Tags: android, image, android-viewpager, picasso

Picasso load all the images from my drawable but i have an issue of the 3rd image disappearing from my view Pager. its not the 3rd image in  particular but any image that comes 3rd, as i swipe on and later swipe back i get the same image showing on my view Pager but the problem persists when i restart the app again. why is this delay in loading image, i basically get a blank screen on the 3rd swipe, i checked if it was a problem with my image but no its not,  if i remove it this disease infects the image which substitutes the earlier 3rd image. this is the code to load the image,

`

```
            @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
                 Context context =getApplicationContext();
                 final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
              int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
                  R.dimen.padding_medium);
              imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);




            Picasso.with(context).load(mImages[position]).error(R.drawable.c3).skipMemoryCache().resize(320,280).centerInside()
                .into(imageView);

                 // use ImageView
            PicassoTools.clearCache(Picasso.with(context));
              ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
              imageView.setTag("myview" + position);

              return imageView;
            }`
```

please analyze and help me out. thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you solve it? Please help me

Comment: @Ravi yes i solved it but i used universal image loader to solve it... picasso didnt help much.

Comment: better late then never. I too solved with UIL